# is it possible to draw lines by mousemove without using canvas in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Using canvas we can able to draw lines when mousemove. I need to know is it possible to draw lines without using canvas by mouse event in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible:

Use this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Bob the Painter </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    td{
    width:10px; /*Change it As You want */
    height:10px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:0px;
    cursor:crosshair;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawLine(x){
    x.style.background="#000000"; /* Use Color Picker for More Colors */
    }
    function drawmyTable(x,y){
    var ground=document.getElementById("html");
    var p="<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>";
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
    p+="<tr>";
    for(var j=0;j<y;j++){
    p+="<td onMouseOver='drawLine(this);'></td>";
    }
    p+="</tr>";
    } 
    p+="</table>";
    ground.innerHTML+=""+p+"";
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body OnLoad="drawmyTable(50,50);" id="html">
    </body>
    </html>
```

It'll create a table with dimensions you specified and when you hover the cell in table it'll change its background color. When you move mouse it'll change the background color of path to `black`.
ofcourse this isn't as much accurate that of `<canvas>` but it is useful in older browsers.

Hope This'll Help you ! Cheers !!